# Javascript animation not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

This piece of js code won't run in IE (tested in 9, 10 and 11), what could be the problem?

```
    function animation() {
    var speed = 3000;
    var container = $('.display-animation');
    container.each(function () {
        var elements = $(this).children();
        elements.each(function () {
            var elementOffset = $(this).offset();
            var offset = elementOffset.left * 0.8 + elementOffset.top;
            var delay = parseFloat(offset / speed).toFixed(2);
            $(this)
              .css("-webkit-animation-delay", delay + 's')
              .css("-o-animation-delay", delay + 's')
              .css("animation-delay", delay + 's')
              .addClass('animated');
        });
    });
}
window.onload = animation;
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/cesikiwefe

It runs perfectly in Chrome.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nothing happens for me in that linked jsbin (running Firefox); it's just a blank window.

Comment: @Pointy I  meant  to say chrome only, don't know why I also typed firefox

Comment: "Not working" is not a diagnostic. Do you get any errors? What component of this do you think is malfunctioning?

Comment: @JohnMcCarty Can you post a JSFiddle instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the JS that you included. The problem is within the CSS of your JS Bin example. You have vendor-specific variants for your keyframes at-rule, but are always using `-webkit-transform` within each of these, so in the case of IE, you need to change:

```
@-ms-keyframes display {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

to:

```
@-ms-keyframes display {
  from {
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Same applies for the other declarations. The problem with the above is that vendor-specific prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`, and `-moz-` are only processed by the browser that specifically supports that prefix (Chrome/Safari/other WebKit-based browsers, Opera, Internet Explorer, and Firefox respectively). Other browsers will (or should) ignore the other prefixes, so Internet Explorer is reading `@-ms-keyframes display`, further interpreting your `from` and `to` rules, getting to your `-webkit-transform` properties, deciding "I have no idea what that means -- it must not be important", and happily continuing as if it were the most normal thing in the world to have an animation without any properties for any of its rules.